# CSS: Is it possible to nest a div with a height of 100% inside a div with a height of auto?

Tags: css, html, nested, divide

I'm trying to use a div as a divider inside of another div and it's not showing up.  I figured if I set the height on the divider div to 100% it would automatically adjust to the height of the containing div, which I have set to "auto" for the height.

If I change the height of the containing div to an exact pixel amount the dividing div kicks in and works fine.  The reason I want it to adjust automatically is because there will be multiple instances of the containing div with different content which will make the height vary from one to the other so just setting an exact pixel amount for all of them won't be sufficient.

Here's the CSS I created

```
.container{
    width:600px;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    }
 #divider{
    width:4px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    }
```

Is my coding wrong or is there something else at play that makes this not possible?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: you could using some display or relative/absolute positionning and coordonates, a border maybe , etc ... , could you give a code snippet here or on a fiddle/codepen to clarify your issue ?

Comment: you mean and html snippet?

Answer (score 1):

100% is relative to the parent. Try making it 100 vh. [Codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/eNqQgO)

```
#divider{
  width:4px;
  height:100vh;
  float:left;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: this made it go the length of the entire page, and I do indeed want it to be relative to the parent div.

Comment: You need to give the divider a specific height. If you do a percentage, it will be a percentage relative to the parent. If the parent is auto, it will default to 0. So it doesn't need to be 100vh, but it needs to be a specific vh or px amount. or have content in it, so that it has a height.

Comment: Ok that answers my question, thanks for making that clear for me.  Guess I'll just do the styling in the html individually for each container rather than trying to have a class or id for it.